# Flutter - Add a Row above Bottom Navigation Bar

Tags: flutter, soundcloud

I would like to know how to add a row, which upon clicking on will function like Bottom Sheet above Bottom Navigation Bar.

Like this image [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gePeW.png)

(The darker row).

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add some code snippets that you have tried or some research that you have already done

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can use a Scaffold property that called `persistentFooterButtons`, and you can add a widget to it, this is an image of the app https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tb4iA.jpg, and this is the code for making the app.

```
void main() async {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  static const TextStyle optionStyle =
      TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold);
  static const List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
    Text(
      'Index 0: Home',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
    Text(
      'Index 1: Business',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
    Text(
      'Index 2: School',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
```

=================== this is all you need  ==============================

```
        persistentFooterButtons: [
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              IconButton(
                iconSize: 35,
                icon: Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
                onPressed: null,
              ),
              Container(child: Text("Some data over hereSome data ")),
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.favorite),
                onPressed: null,
              )
            ],
          )
        ],
```

=================================================

```
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.home),
              title: Text('Home'),
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.business),
              title: Text('Business'),
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.school),
              title: Text('School'),
            ),
          ],
          currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
          selectedItemColor: Colors.amber[800],
          onTap: _onItemTapped,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An [Expanded Widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html) should solve your issue. The video and documentation is at the link. It should allow for a row to be placed/pushed to the bottom of the screen so that it is "above" the navigation bar. Simply wrap your widget with an expanded widget.